# Reinf - Problemas ao atribuir conteúdo na tag Reference URI

Tags: java, uri, web-service

Alguém já passou por esta situação? Erro ao atribuir conteúdo na tag de assinatura: Signature -> Reference -> URI

Ao atribuir conteúdo na tag de Assinatura Reference URI estou recebendo uma **EXCEPTION**, veja abaixo:

> javax.xml.crypto.dsig.XMLSignatureException: javax.xml.crypto.URIReferenceException: com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.utils.resolver.ResourceResolverException: Cannout resolve element with ID IDnnnnnnnnnn

Em algumas literaturas / fórum, citam, que eu já fiz, a implementação do código:

```
...
String id = el.getAttribute("id");  
el.setIdAttribute("id", true);  
... 
Reference ref = fac.newReference("#".concat(id), fac.newDigestMethod("http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256", null),transformList, null, null);  
...
```

O "id" está exatamente desta forma no XML de entrada. O conteúdo do ID no Reference está sendo gerado corretamente, porém quando executa o camando abaixo, recebo esta **exception**. 
( Cannout resolve element with ID IDnnnnnnnnnn )

```
signature.sign(dsc);
```

Comment: A mensagem diz "*Cannout*" ou diz "*Cannot*"?

Comment: OsvaldoMenezes, dá uma olhada nesse link e vê se é o seu caso: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8017265

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realmente, em algumas literaturas que pesquisei, o RUIReferenceException é atualização da versão do JAVA pela ORACLE.

Porém o erro em meu caso foi que havia no fonte duas INSTÂNCIAS do DOCUMENT.
Sendo que uma delas (EX: DOC) estava tratando o ID e noutra (EX> DOCS)estava tratando a ASSINATURA.

Eliminei uma das instâncias, corrigindo o código e RESOLVEU.